# Is there a way to adjust Vibrance in the compositor?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, node-editor, compositing-nodes, color-management

There is of course a node that deals with saturation but I'm not finding anything for vibrance values like in Photoshop which I find a bit more useful. This would be a very helpful thing to include in trunk in the future I think. Or if anyone knows of a way to make a node like that or an add-on. Thanks!

Comment: Hello :). There are some threads on [Photography SE](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/9385) inclusing a [detailed analysis](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/9398) of Adobe's Vibrance algorithm. This should help with recreating it in Blender's *compositor nodes*.

Comment: Thank you, these are helpful!